# Spatial Join Attribution for Report Generation

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcmap, map-book

I generated a grid index for a very large area of land in order to create a mapbook to keep track of some environmental sites for monitoring.  I was able to generate the pages of maps without issue, however, I now wish to tabulate the sites (small polygons) contained within each individual map (grid index cell) in a separate file to append to the map book.  I spatially joined the small polygons to the grid index cells so that I could index the sites by page number.

When I generate a report (extracting only the PageNumber and Site ID in order to create a checklist for each map page), I cannot get the report to group this data into separate pages.  It just generates a running spreadsheet in ascending order.  What I am aiming for is to create a document where every page contains only the sites for each respective PageNumber.
I thought it would be straight forward but I can't figure it out and don't want to export to an excel file to manually separate 75 pages worth of sites.

Comment: Just to clarify: you want the output Excel file to have each page's data in a separate sheet, instead of all in one sheet?

Comment: Correct.  Each map page's data would be in a separate sheet.  I would ideally like to just use the Report Generator as the final output needs to be as a .pdf in order to append that report with the mapbook.